# My Data keeps trending downwards even though it's equal probabilities

Tags: python, random, while-loop, probability

So I would just like to ask for a bit of help with this. Please be aware that I am fairly new to python so my following code will not be the cleanest, I will gladly and would love your tips and advice for how to make it better, **BUT** my main question is regarding the code below.

If you were to run it, you can run it every "minute" for a year (this is what I have been doing), and generate a "value" every minute based on probabilities.

But for some reason, it keeps trending downwards towards the end, and I have no idea why. I ran 100 files whilst I was at work, and I just checked them, and AGAIN (I have tested this multiple times), most of the files trend downwards.

i.e. I start with 1000, and I end much lower. This doesn't make sense to me as the probability of either the value going up, down or staying the same is equal.

- Note, I now have it as `up_or_down_decision = random.choices(up_or_down, weights=(33,33,33), k=1)` but before hand I had it as just `up_or_down_decision = random.choice(up_or_down)` and I don't have any difference

Please can someone help me here. I want it to generate a lot of files that look completely different and act completely different.

```
import random
import os
import time

def convert_time(total_run_time):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(total_run_time))

def choice_years():
    f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f'You chose to run for: {range_years} Year(s)\n')
    f.write(f'You will generate data for: {str(iteration_total)} iterations\n')
    f.close()
    print(f'You will generate {str(iteration_total)} entries of data.')
def choice_months():
    f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f'You chose to run for: {range_months} Month(s)\n')
    f.write(f'You will generate data for: {str(iteration_total)} iterations\n')
    f.close()
    print(f'You will generate {str(iteration_total)} entries of data.')
def choice_days():
    f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f'You chose to run for: {range_days} Day(s)\n')
    f.write(f'You will generate data for: {str(iteration_total)} iterations\n')
    f.close()
    print(f'You will generate {str(iteration_total)} entries of data.')
def choice_hours():
    f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f'You chose to run for: {range_hours} Hour(s)\n')
    f.write(f'You will generate data for: {str(iteration_total)} iterations\n')
    f.close()
    print(f'You will generate {str(iteration_total)} entries of data.')

# Name_Number of Files_Time Geration_Number of Y/M/D/H_Every how many minutes 
folder = 'Dummy_Data_4.csv'
os.mkdir(folder)

FILE_INPUT = input('Please choose the name of the .txt file you want to write to:\n')
FILE_NUMBER = int(input('\nHow many files do you want to generate?:\n'))
f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'w')
f.write(f'You chose to generate {str(FILE_NUMBER)} file(s)\n')
f.close()

iteration = input('\nEvery how many minutes do you want data?:\n')
f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
f.write(f'You chose to generate data every: {iteration} minute(s)\n')
f.close()

if iteration.isdigit():
    time_duration = input('\nDo you want to run it for Years, Months, Days, or Hours?:\n1. Years\n2. Months\n3. Days\n4. Hours\n')
    if time_duration == '1' or time_duration == 'Years' or time_duration == '1. Years' or time_duration == 'Y' or time_duration == 'years' or time_duration == '1. years' or time_duration == 'y':
        print('\nYou chose Years') 
        range_years = input('How many Years? Please input an integer:\n')
        iteration_total = int((int(range_years) * 525600)/int(iteration))
        choice_years()
    elif time_duration == '2' or time_duration == 'Months' or time_duration == '2. Months' or time_duration == 'M' or time_duration == 'months' or time_duration == '2. months' or time_duration == 'm':
        print('\nYou chose Months')
        range_months = input('How many Months? Please input an integer (Note: The average number of days for a month will be taken as 30):\n')
        iteration_total = int((int(range_months) * 43200)/int(iteration))
        choice_months()
    elif time_duration == '3' or time_duration == 'Days' or time_duration == '3. Days' or time_duration == 'D' or time_duration == 'days' or time_duration == '3. days' or time_duration == 'd':
        print('\nYou chose Days')
        range_days = input('How many Days? Please input an integer:\n')
        iteration_total = int((int(range_days) * 1440)/int(iteration))
        choice_days()
    elif time_duration == '4' or time_duration == 'Hours' or time_duration == '4. Hours' or time_duration == 'H' or time_duration == 'hours' or time_duration == '4. hours' or time_duration == 'h':
        print('\nYou chose Hours')
        range_hours = input('How many Hours? Please input an integer:\n')
        iteration_total = int((int(range_hours) * 60)/int(iteration))
        choice_hours()
    else:
        print('Your choice is invalid, goodbye')
        exit()
else:
    print('Your input was incorrect, goodbye')
    exit()

starting_price = float(input('\nWhat is your starting price?:\n'))
new_price = float('%.2f' % starting_price)
print('Your starting price is ' + 'R%.2f' % starting_price)
f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
f.write('Your starting price is: ' + 'R%.2f' % starting_price + '\n' + '\n')
f.close()

i = 1
j = 1
kick_off_time = time.time()
while j <= FILE_NUMBER:
    NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION = FILE_INPUT + '_' + str(j)
    CSV_FILE_WRITE = FILE_INPUT + '_' + str(j) + '.csv'
    print(CSV_FILE_WRITE)
    i = 1
    j += 1
    new_price = float('%.2f' % starting_price)
    start_time = time.time()
    while i <= iteration_total:
        up_or_down = ['up', 'down', 'none']
        up_or_down_decision = random.choices(up_or_down, weights=(33,33,33), k=1)
        if up_or_down_decision[0] == 'up':
            change_list = [0.001, 0.002, 0.00005, 0.01, 0.003]
            change_decision = random.choice(change_list)
            added_price = new_price * change_decision
            new_price = new_price + added_price
            formatted_new_price = float('%.2f' % new_price)
            f = open(f'./{folder}/' + CSV_FILE_WRITE, 'a')
            f.write(f'{str(i)},{str(formatted_new_price)} \n')
            f.close()
            i += 1
        elif up_or_down_decision[0] == 'down':
            change_list = [0.001, 0.002, 0.00005, 0.01, 0.003]
            change_decision = random.choice(change_list)
            subtracted_price = new_price * change_decision
            new_price = new_price - subtracted_price
            formatted_new_price = float('%.2f' % new_price)
            f = open(f'./{folder}/' + CSV_FILE_WRITE, 'a')
            f.write(f'{str(i)},{str(formatted_new_price)} \n')
            f.close()
            i += 1
        elif up_or_down_decision[0] == 'none':
            formatted_new_price = float('%.2f' % new_price)
            end_time = time.time()
            iteration_time = float('%.2f' % (end_time - start_time))
            f = open(f'./{folder}/' + CSV_FILE_WRITE, 'a')
            f.write(f'{str(i)},{str(formatted_new_price)} \n')
            f.close()
            i += 1
    end_time = time.time()
    iteration_time = '%.5f' % float(end_time - start_time)
    f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f'{CSV_FILE_WRITE}: {iteration_time} seconds \n')
    f.close()
termination_time = time.time()
total_run_time = termination_time - kick_off_time
f = open(f'./{folder}/Details.txt', 'a')
f.write(f'Total Run Time: {convert_time(total_run_time)} seconds')
f.close()
```

Comment: This was an interesting question! It took a while to figure out what was going on here: Before posting next question, read how to make minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . By doing that you probably would have find solution yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add or subtract persentage from your previous sum. Each persentage are equally possible and adding or subtracting are equally possible.

Think what happens here. You first add 1% to 1000 and then substract 1% from the result and repeat a few times over and over again. Your end result will be less than 1000.  Try yourself:

```py
def tryit():
    print("Ten rounds, substracting first")
    price = 1000
    for x in range(10):
        if x%2 == 0: 
            price -= price*0.01
        else:
            price += price*0.01
        print(price)
    
    print("Ten rounds, adding first")
    price = 1000
    for x in range(10):
        if x%2 == 0: 
            price += price*0.01
        else:
            price -= price*0.01
        print(price)
        
        
tryit()
```

Your end price less than 1000 even if you add and then substract same persentage over and over again.

Why is this?

- First round: 1000 * 0.01 -> add 10 -> new price = 1010
- Second round: 1010 * 0.01 -> substract 10.1 -> new price = 999.90

If we start by substracting, we end to the same effect:

- Frist round: 1000 * 0.01  -> substract 10 -> new price = 990
- Second round: 990 * 0.01  -> add 9.9 -> new price = 999.9

This behaviour is happening there, even if you add some random elements there.

So how to keep this balanced? Do not add or substract, multiply and divide instead.

```py
def thisworks():
    print("Ten rounds, substracting first")
    price = 1000
    for x in range(10):
        if x%2 == 0: 
            price = price*1.01
        else:
            price = price/1.01
        print(price)
    print("Ten rounds, adding first")
    price = 1000
    for x in range(10):
        if x%2 == 0: 
            price = price/1.01
        else:
            price = price*1.01
        print(price)
        
        
thisworks()
```

And putting it to your code (just a part of it):

```
 while i <= iteration_total:
        up_or_down = ['up', 'down', 'none']
        up_or_down_decision = random.choices(up_or_down, weights=(33,33,33), k=1)
        if up_or_down_decision[0] == 'up':
            change_list = [0.001, 0.002, 0.00005, 0.01, 0.003]
            change_decision = random.choice(change_list)
            # XXX Change here
            # added_price = new_price * change_decision
            # new_price = new_price + added_price
            new_price = new_price * (1+change_decision)
            formatted_new_price = float('%.2f' % new_price)
            f = open(f'./{folder}/' + CSV_FILE_WRITE, 'a')
            f.write(f'{str(i)},{str(formatted_new_price)} \n')
            f.close()
            i += 1
        elif up_or_down_decision[0] == 'down':
            change_list = [0.001, 0.002, 0.00005, 0.01, 0.003]
            change_decision = random.choice(change_list)
            # XXX Change here
            # subtracted_price = new_price * change_decision
            # new_price = new_price - subtracted_price
            new_price = new_price / (1+change_decision)
            formatted_new_price = float('%.2f' % new_price)
            f = open(f'./{folder}/' + CSV_FILE_WRITE, 'a')
            f.write(f'{str(i)},{str(formatted_new_price)} \n')
            f.close()
            i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow I didn't even think about this!!! Thank you so much! I am literally getting out of bed now to fix it and see if it works